# ffmpeg drawtext performance

Tags: ffmpeg

Im running the following command within PHP using shell_exec:

```
ffmpeg -i $sourcePath -vf \"drawtext=text='$txt':fontfile='$fontPath':fontcolor='red':fontsize='40':x=w-mod(max(t-1\,0)*(w+tw)/30\,(w+tw)):y=main_h/2\" -acodec copy $targetPath
```

It works fine but it takes for ever.  A 3 minutes video takes 5 minutes to process.  Any recomendation in how to improve performance?

Comment: If the output video encoder is libx264 or libx265, you can add `-preset veryfast`. In any case, drawtext isn't the limiting factor.

Comment: How do i set the output video encoder to libx264?

Comment: Add `-c:v libx264`

Comment: You should put your comment as answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use GPU decoding and encoding to speed it up.
My code works with GeForce GTX video card.

```
ffmpeg 
    -hwaccel_device 0              
    -hwaccel cuvid                
    -c:v h264_cuvid
    -i $sourcePath 
    -vf hwdownload,format=nv12,drawtext=text='$txt':fontfile='$fontPath':fontcolor='red':fontsize='40':x=w-mod(max(t-1\,0)*(w+tw)/30\,(w+tw)):y=main_h/2,hwupload
    -acodec copy 
    $targetPath
```